# How to use the MultiTouchController library? (Android)

Tags: android, android-view, multi-touch

I want to manipulate a library I just discovered to drag/rotate and pinch zoom images. I am using two sources:

-The library itself: MultiTouchController.java https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/source/browse/MTController/src/org/metalev/multitouch/controller/MultiTouchController.java

-An implementation of this library: `PhotoSortrView` https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/source/browse/MTPhotoSortr/src/org/metalev/multitouch/photosortr/PhotoSortrView.java

My issue is that I want to use this in a `Activity` that displays an `ImageView` in the center of the screen, and that image **is not supposed to move**. With the current code, the `PhotoSortrView` is the contentView of the `Activity` and it seems impossible to make it a sub element of some layout. So I figured I would implement that image as a `Img` and modify the code of `PhotoSortrView` to freeze that one `Img`, by adding a boolean frozen attribute for instance.

However, I don't know which method I would use to actually block that `Img`.

Do you know how to use this library to freeze an `Img`? I think someone who has already used that library may find it easier but it is not a requirement. I am quite new to Android so that library may be easy to understand and my issue is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 160 (https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/source/browse/MTPhotoSortr/src/org/metalev/multitouch/photosortr/PhotoSortrView.java#160) to

```
if (im.containsPoint(x, y) && i!=theImageInTheCenter)
```

and, define the variable

```
int theImageInTheCenter = 3;
```

if its for example the 3rd image (R.drawable.tahiti) that shoulnt move

Comment: It worked just as expected, thanks a lot @Jacod Nordfalk. I'm curious, did you know that library or did you just find out the solution?

Comment: Ive used the library a few times, so I knew the code pretty much

Comment: if that's the case maybe you could help me out if another issue regarding this library I posted here. I would like to retain the state of the images when the Activity displaying them is killed.